# loading xml into SQL Server 2008 using sqlbulkload component

Tags: sql-server, xml

"Error: Schema: relationship expected on 'headerRecord'."

I get the above error while load xml file to SQL Server 2008 using SQLXMLBulkLoad4 Component , the xml file contains Call Detail records, I have generated schema file from xml file using both , Dataset and XSD.exe tool, but the error remains same., if there is another way to imports xml file with multiple tables that have relationship in each file into SQL Server 2008? .

Here the xml file:

```
<CallEventDataFile>
<headerRecord>
<productionDateTime>0912021247482B0300</productionDateTime>
<recordingEntity>00</recordingEntity>
<extensions/>
</headerRecord>
<callEventRecords>
<mtSMSRecord>
  <recordType>7</recordType>
  <serviceCentre>91521230</serviceCentre>
  <servedIMSI>36570000031728F2</servedIMSI>
  <servedIMEI>53886000707896F0</servedIMEI>
  <servedMSISDN>915212454503F2</servedMSISDN>
  <msClassmark>3319A1</msClassmark>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <location>
    <locationAreaCode>0006</locationAreaCode>
    <cellIdentifier>0C6E</cellIdentifier>
  </location>
  <deliveryTime>0912021535412B0300</deliveryTime>
  <systemType>
    <gERAN/>
  </systemType>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>21</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <chargedParty>
    <calledParty/>
  </chargedParty>
  <orgRNCorBSCId>8E1A</orgRNCorBSCId>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <globalAreaID>36F70500060C6E</globalAreaID>
  <subscriberCategory>0A</subscriberCategory>
  <firstmccmnc>36F705</firstmccmnc>
  <smsUserDataType>FF</smsUserDataType>
  <origination>8191F2</origination>
  <callReference>1605EB2FE1</callReference>
</mtSMSRecord>
<moSMSRecord>
  <recordType>6</recordType>
  <servedIMSI>36570000238707F9</servedIMSI>
  <servedIMEI>53928320195925F0</servedIMEI>
  <servedMSISDN>915212159430F2</servedMSISDN>
  <msClassmark>3319A2</msClassmark>
  <serviceCentre>91521230</serviceCentre>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <location>
    <locationAreaCode>001B</locationAreaCode>
    <cellIdentifier>6983</cellIdentifier>
  </location>
  <messageReference>01</messageReference>
  <originationTime>0912021535412B0300</originationTime>
  <destinationNumber>8111F1</destinationNumber>
  <systemType>
    <gERAN/>
  </systemType>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>22</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <chargedParty>
    <callingParty/>
  </chargedParty>
  <orgRNCorBSCId>8F1A</orgRNCorBSCId>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <globalAreaID>36F705001B6983</globalAreaID>
  <subscriberCategory>0A</subscriberCategory>
  <firstmccmnc>36F705</firstmccmnc>
  <smsUserDataType>FF</smsUserDataType>
  <callReference>1701BED4FF</callReference>
</moSMSRecord>
<ssActionRecord>
  <recordType>10</recordType>
  <servedIMSI>36570000636448F8</servedIMSI>
  <servedIMEI>53246030714961F0</servedIMEI>
  <servedMSISDN>915212056928F8</servedMSISDN>
  <msClassmark>3018A1</msClassmark>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <location>
    <locationAreaCode>000C</locationAreaCode>
    <cellIdentifier>05A5</cellIdentifier>
  </location>
  <supplService>FF</supplService>
  <ssAction>
    <ussdInvocation/>
  </ssAction>
  <ssActionTime>0912021535412B0300</ssActionTime>
  <ssParameters>
    <unstructuredData>AA5C2E3702</unstructuredData>
  </ssParameters>
  <callReference>1701BED500</callReference>
  <systemType>
    <gERAN/>
  </systemType>
  <ussdCodingScheme>0F</ussdCodingScheme>
  <ussdString>
    <UssdString>AA5C2E3702</UssdString>
  </ussdString>
  <ussdRequestCounter>1</ussdRequestCounter>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>1</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <orgRNCorBSCId>8E1A</orgRNCorBSCId>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <globalAreaID>36F705000C05A5</globalAreaID>
  <subscriberCategory>0A</subscriberCategory>
  <firstmccmnc>36F705</firstmccmnc>
</ssActionRecord>
<moCallRecord>
  <recordType>0</recordType>
  <servedIMSI>36570000807501F5</servedIMSI>
  <servedIMEI>53246030713955F0</servedIMEI>
  <servedMSISDN>915212157901F0</servedMSISDN>
  <callingNumber>A151911700</callingNumber>
  <calledNumber>8151677589</calledNumber>
  <roamingNumber>A111113850</roamingNumber>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <mscIncomingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>HWBSC2</rOUTEName>
  </mscIncomingROUTE>
  <mscOutgoingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>HWBSC2</rOUTEName>
  </mscOutgoingROUTE>
  <location>
    <locationAreaCode>0006</locationAreaCode>
    <cellIdentifier>0C2F</cellIdentifier>
  </location>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>11</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <msClassmark>3319A1</msClassmark>
  <answerTime>0912021535382B0300</answerTime>
  <releaseTime>0912021535422B0300</releaseTime>
  <callDuration>4</callDuration>
  <radioChanRequested>
    <dualFullRatePreferred/>
  </radioChanRequested>
  <radioChanUsed>
    <halfRate/>
  </radioChanUsed>
  <causeForTerm>0</causeForTerm>
  <diagnostics>
    <gsm0408Cause>144</gsm0408Cause>
  </diagnostics>
  <callReference>1701BED501</callReference>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <gsm-SCFAddress>915212110130</gsm-SCFAddress>
  <serviceKey>1</serviceKey>
  <networkCallReference>171D555132</networkCallReference>
  <mSCAddress>915212110100</mSCAddress>
  <speechVersionSupported>25</speechVersionSupported>
  <speechVersionUsed>21</speechVersionUsed>
  <numberOfDPEncountered>3</numberOfDPEncountered>
  <levelOfCAMELService>01</levelOfCAMELService>
  <freeFormatData>800130</freeFormatData>
  <systemType>
    <gERAN/>
  </systemType>
  <classmark3>C000</classmark3>
  <chargedParty>
    <callingParty/>
  </chargedParty>
  <mscOutgoingCircuit>1051</mscOutgoingCircuit>
  <orgRNCorBSCId>8E1A</orgRNCorBSCId>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <calledIMSI>36570000635618F8</calledIMSI>
  <globalAreaID>36F70500060C2F</globalAreaID>
  <subscriberCategory>0A</subscriberCategory>
  <firstmccmnc>36F705</firstmccmnc>
  <lastmccmnc>36F705</lastmccmnc>
</moCallRecord>
<mtCallRecord>
  <recordType>1</recordType>
  <servedIMSI>36570000635618F8</servedIMSI>
  <servedIMEI>53464010474309F0</servedIMEI>
  <servedMSISDN>915212755697F8</servedMSISDN>
  <callingNumber>A151911700</callingNumber>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <mscIncomingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>HWBSC2</rOUTEName>
  </mscIncomingROUTE>
  <mscOutgoingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>HWBSC2</rOUTEName>
  </mscOutgoingROUTE>
  <location>
    <locationAreaCode>0006</locationAreaCode>
    <cellIdentifier>0C2D</cellIdentifier>
  </location>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>11</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <supplServicesUsed>
    <SuppServiceUsedid>
      <ssCode>11</ssCode>
      <ssTime>0912021535382B0300</ssTime>
    </SuppServiceUsedid>
  </supplServicesUsed>
  <msClassmark>331981</msClassmark>
  <answerTime>0912021535382B0300</answerTime>
  <releaseTime>0912021535422B0300</releaseTime>
  <callDuration>4</callDuration>
  <radioChanRequested>
    <dualFullRatePreferred/>
  </radioChanRequested>
  <radioChanUsed>
    <halfRate/>
  </radioChanUsed>
  <causeForTerm>0</causeForTerm>
  <diagnostics>
    <gsm0408Cause>144</gsm0408Cause>
  </diagnostics>
  <callReference>1701BED502</callReference>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <networkCallReference>171D555132</networkCallReference>
  <mSCAddress>915212110100</mSCAddress>
  <speechVersionSupported>25</speechVersionSupported>
  <speechVersionUsed>21</speechVersionUsed>
  <systemType>
    <gERAN/>
  </systemType>
  <classmark3>C000</classmark3>
  <chargedParty>
    <calledParty/>
  </chargedParty>
  <roamingNumber>A111113850</roamingNumber>
  <mscIncomingCircuit>9119</mscIncomingCircuit>
  <orgRNCorBSCId>8E1A</orgRNCorBSCId>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <globalAreaID>36F70500060C2D</globalAreaID>
  <subscriberCategory>0A</subscriberCategory>
  <firstmccmnc>36F705</firstmccmnc>
  <lastmccmnc>36F705</lastmccmnc>
</mtCallRecord>
<incGatewayRecord>
  <recordType>3</recordType>
  <callingNumber>A17005991565</callingNumber>
  <calledNumber>A1853643F7</calledNumber>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <mscIncomingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>ZPSTN</rOUTEName>
  </mscIncomingROUTE>
  <mscOutgoingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>ZTEBSC3</rOUTEName>
  </mscOutgoingROUTE>
  <answerTime>0912021535302B0300</answerTime>
  <releaseTime>0912021535422B0300</releaseTime>
  <callDuration>12</callDuration>
  <causeForTerm>0</causeForTerm>
  <diagnostics>
    <gsm0408Cause>144</gsm0408Cause>
  </diagnostics>
  <callReference>2203AFBF84</callReference>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>11</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <roamingNumber>A111111980</roamingNumber>
  <mscIncomingCircuit>934</mscIncomingCircuit>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <mscIncomingRouteAttribute>
    <isup/>
  </mscIncomingRouteAttribute>
  <networkCallReference>22432B5132</networkCallReference>
</incGatewayRecord>
<outGatewayRecord>
  <recordType>4</recordType>
  <callingNumber>A151012431</callingNumber>
  <calledNumber>817026936873</calledNumber>
  <recordingEntity>915212110100</recordingEntity>
  <mscIncomingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>HWBSC</rOUTEName>
  </mscIncomingROUTE>
  <mscOutgoingROUTE>
    <rOUTEName>ZPSTN</rOUTEName>
  </mscOutgoingROUTE>
  <answerTime>0912021535192B0300</answerTime>
  <releaseTime>0912021535432B0300</releaseTime>
  <callDuration>24</callDuration>
  <causeForTerm>0</causeForTerm>
  <diagnostics>
    <gsm0408Cause>144</gsm0408Cause>
  </diagnostics>
  <callReference>2303B19880</callReference>
  <basicService>
    <teleservice>11</teleservice>
  </basicService>
  <additionalChgInfo>
    <chargeIndicator>2</chargeIndicator>
  </additionalChgInfo>
  <mscOutgoingCircuit>398</mscOutgoingCircuit>
  <orgMSCId>921A</orgMSCId>
  <mscOutgoingRouteAttribute>
    <isup/>
  </mscOutgoingRouteAttribute>
  <networkCallReference>238BE55132</networkCallReference>
</outGatewayRecord>
</callEventRecords>
<trailerRecord>
<productionDateTime>0912021247512B0300</productionDateTime>
<recordingEntity>00</recordingEntity>
<firstCallDateTime>000000000000000000</firstCallDateTime>
<lastCallDateTime>000000000000000000</lastCallDateTime>
<noOfRecords>521</noOfRecords>
<extensions/>
</trailerRecord>
<extensions/>
</CallEventDataFile>
```

Schema File generated by Dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="location">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="locationAreaCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="cellIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="systemType">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="gERAN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="basicService">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="teleservice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="additionalChgInfo">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="chargeIndicator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="chargedParty">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="calledParty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="callingParty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="mscIncomingROUTE">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="rOUTEName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="mscOutgoingROUTE">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="rOUTEName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="radioChanRequested">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="dualFullRatePreferred" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="radioChanUsed">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="halfRate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="diagnostics">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="gsm0408Cause" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CallEventDataFile">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="extensions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="headerRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="productionDateTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="extensions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="callEventRecords" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="mtSMSRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="recordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="serviceCentre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMEI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedMSISDN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="msClassmark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="deliveryTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgRNCorBSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgMSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="globalAreaID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="subscriberCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="firstmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="smsUserDataType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="origination" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element ref="location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="systemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="basicService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="additionalChgInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="chargedParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="moSMSRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="recordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMEI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedMSISDN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="msClassmark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="serviceCentre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="messageReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="originationTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="destinationNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgRNCorBSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgMSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="globalAreaID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="subscriberCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="firstmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="smsUserDataType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element ref="location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="systemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="basicService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="additionalChgInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="chargedParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="ssActionRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="recordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMEI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedMSISDN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="msClassmark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="supplService" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ssActionTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ussdCodingScheme" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ussdRequestCounter" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgRNCorBSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgMSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="globalAreaID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="subscriberCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="firstmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element ref="location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="ssAction" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="ussdInvocation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ssParameters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="unstructuredData" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="systemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="ussdString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="UssdString" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="additionalChgInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="moCallRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="recordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMEI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedMSISDN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callingNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="calledNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="roamingNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="msClassmark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="answerTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="releaseTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callDuration" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="causeForTerm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="gsm-SCFAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="serviceKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="networkCallReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mSCAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="speechVersionSupported" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="speechVersionUsed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="numberOfDPEncountered" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="levelOfCAMELService" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="freeFormatData" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="classmark3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mscOutgoingCircuit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgRNCorBSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgMSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="calledIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="globalAreaID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="subscriberCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="firstmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="lastmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element ref="mscIncomingROUTE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="mscOutgoingROUTE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="basicService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="radioChanRequested" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="radioChanUsed" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="diagnostics" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="additionalChgInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="systemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="chargedParty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="mtCallRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="recordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMSI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedIMEI" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="servedMSISDN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callingNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="recordingEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="msClassmark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="answerTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="releaseTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callDuration" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="causeForTerm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="callReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="networkCallReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mSCAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="speechVersionSupported" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="speechVersionUsed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="classmark3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="roamingNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mscIncomingCircuit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgRNCorBSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="orgMSCId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="globalAreaID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="subscriberCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="firstmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="lastmccmnc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element ref="mscIncomingROUTE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="mscOutgoingROUTE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="basicService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="supplServicesUsed" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="SuppServiceUsedid" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ssCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ssTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          </xs:sequence>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: the error is "Error: Schema: relationship expected on 'headerRecord'."

Answer (score 0):

Where and how do you want to import this XML file??

SQL Server 2005 and up has pretty extensive support for XQuery, which means you can extract bits of information from your XML using XPath.

Not knowing what you're trying to do, here's just a quick sample_

```
DECLARE @XmlContent XML
SET @XmlContent = '(put your XML here)'

SELECT
  @XmlContent.value('(/CallEventDataFile/headerRecord/productionDateTime)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Production DateTime',
  @XmlContent.value('(/CallEventDataFile/headerRecord/recordingEntity)[1]', 'int') as 'Recording Entity'
```

With this XQuery syntax, you can extract pretty much everything from your XML and easily store it into a table column.

Also, if you need to enumerate a list of XML nodes that are inside a XML tag, you can use the `.nodes()` function on XML:

```
SELECT 
   mtsms.record.value('(recordType)[1]', 'int') as 'Record Type',
   mtsms.record.value('(serviceCentre)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as 'Service Centre'
FROM
   @XmlContents.nodes('//mtSMSRecord') AS mtsms(record)
```

With this statement, you could get a "virtual table" of all `<mtSMSRecord>` nodes in your XML as a table "mtsms" and column "record", and you could then extract detail information for each mtSMSRecord tag and store that into your relational tables, as needed.

A really good introduction to XML support in SQL Server 2005 and up is the [An Overview of XML Support in SQL Server 2005](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm) article on 15seconds. It shows you what XML functions are available and how to use them.